# PostgreSQL query with the data from the references table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

items

```
------------------
| item_id | text |
------------------

CREATE TABLE items (
item_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
text varchar
);
```

activity

```
------------------------
| message_id | item_id |
------------------------

CREATE TABLE activity (
message_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
item_id varchar not null references items(item_id)
);
```

How to correctly make a query with the data from the **items** table?
I need to find by value **message_id** or **item_id**

I tried:

```
select * from items, activity where items.item_id = activity.item_id and activity.item_id = 'it123';

select * from activity, items where activity.item_id = items.item_id and 'activity.item_id' = 'it123';
```

This true query:

```
SELECT * FROM items JOIN activity ON items.item_id = activity.item_id;
```

And this true query:

```
SELECT * FROM activity WHERE item_id = 'ea02ea57ff1b';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a table `JOIN`. So you could do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM items 
   JOIN activity ON items.item_id = activity.item_id
   WHERE items.item_id = 'it123';
```